# Every time I clone from github I have to copy/paste the stylesheet into a new file?

Tags: css, git

Every time I clone or checkout my project from github, to get the stylesheet working I copy the code from the raw style.css file on github, remove style.css and paste the code into a new style.css. If it makes a difference, the way that I paste is `vim style.css` + `:set paste` + `ctr v`. Or sometimes I even paste directly from the non-working version with `ctrl + c` for cut (to copy) and that works too. And this is a PHP webpage.

I looked into the file with `:set list` to look for hidden characters and there are none, just cash symbols for spaces at the end of each line. What could be causing this?

EDIT: I should probably mention that this I'm doing this all over ssh on a server, and I just realized, for some reason I'm perfectly able to clone to my OS X desktop and transfer the files over with FileZilla, and that works fine. So crises averted I guess. I still do not know what the issue is with cloning directly to the server though.

Comment: do cat -vet filename .. to check for trailing spaces.

Comment: it only happens when cloning or checking out a new project?  .. Also , what happens after fixing the file. Does it keep getting corrupted?

Comment: This is the result of cat -vet filename flip2 ~ 467% cat -vet style.css      
(yM-^EM-HM-}^?flip2 ~ 468%     
????? And no, the fixed ones do not get corrupted.